# wp_pagenavi() with custom wp_query()?

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, loop, plugin-wp-pagenavi

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Projects
*/
?>

<?php get_header();?>

    <section id="content">
        <section id="main">

            <?php
                $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'projects', 'posts_per_page' => 4));
                $i=1;
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            ?>

            <article class="post<?php if($i%2 == 0) { echo ' right'; }; $i++; ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <section class="entry">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </section>
            </article>

            <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_pagenavi();
            ?>

            <section id="map">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/interactive-map.jpg" alt="Interactive Map" />
            </section>
        </section>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have pagenavi set up right after the endwhile. It's not working, though. Anybody know how I can get this to work?

Comment: see - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop (basically you need to hijack the $wp_query global and use it instead of $loop

Comment: I followed the directions in there and the navigation shows now but when I go to page 2, I get an error. Here is the pastebin of what I have. If you can take a look and let me know if you notice anything wrong, I'd be forever grateful. Thank you. http://pastebin.com/RMZaE6Pi

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @One Trick Pony: Can you move your comment to an answer, so John can accept it? Maybe include my comment in the referenced answer, because with the new version of WP-Pagenavi you can pass a `query` argument. John asked [a followup question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9593/custom-post-types-and-wp-pagenavi) to get the paging working.

Answer (score 19):

```
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) );
```

should work with the code above. Don't hijack the main query if you can avoid it.

Comment: My source for this: http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-pagenavi/trunk/core.php#L3

Comment: Indeed, the development version of WP Pagenavi (2.74-alpha) supports this.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was the dev version. Oops!

Comment: is this possible with paginate_links() ?

Comment: `paginate_links` is somewhat more basic. Instead of giving it a query object, you tell it what the max number of pages are, what the current page is, and a few other parameters (like the format of the url, etc.)

Comment: @John P Bloch: Just released it: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html :)

Comment: @scribu: tested it with a custom post type and the pagination doesn't get the active page if > 1, when permalinks are on. Maybe it's related to this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9537/pretty-paged-permalinks-in-custom-post-type-loop

Comment: Did you include 'paged'? If yes, you should ask a new question, with the code sample attached. Also, don't blame pagenavi; it just generates links. :)

Comment: yes. no point opening a new question as I don't use the plugin anymore, just pointing out that it doesn't fully support cpt. You should add another argument to wp_pagenavi(), like 'current' in which you can pass the current page eg. `get_permalink()`

Comment: @john: i got same problem while using offset in custom query post . please help me !   $loop = new WP_Query(array("paged=".get_query_var('paged')."&offset=1"));

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php       // Pagination
        if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) :
            wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $blog_posts_query ) );
        else : ?>
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link() ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link() ?></div>
            </div>
<?php       endif;

                // Restore original Post Data
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```