# Custom post type archive with pagination?

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, archives

I have a custom post type called 'projects' ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jRc7BFCR)) and I have a page called Projects set up in my dashboard which is set to display the Projects template. ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jTSbEqy5))

The problem is when I use WP_PageNavi to incorporate pagination and click on page 2, I get an error 404. I read somewhere that this is because custom post types and pages can't have the same name. And I've found that to be true because I tried changing the page name to "Projects 2" and it worked.

But when I change the name of the custom post type, that gets reflected in the url. So if I change the custom post type to 'projects2' instead of just 'projects', the url now looks like this: mysite.com/projects2/single-post

I have my custom permalinks set to /%category%/%postname%/ by the way.

Likewise, I can't change the name of the page to 'Projects 2' for aesthetic reasons.

So how would I get around this? This has been driving me crazy for many hours. I would really appreciate any helpful advice!

Comment: I guess you have a conflict in your rewrite rules for your custom post type and your page. Can you try [my Rewrite analyzer plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608) and tell me what you get for the URL `projects/page/2/`? It should be `pagename=projects` and `paged=2`, not `projects=page/2/`. (Use `@Jan` when you reply in a comment and I get a notification.)

Comment: Thanks @Jan. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to answer so I took a screenshot: http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/2760/rewrite.gif

Comment: That's great, and it's the problem I suspected. But no problem, we can solve it. It will have to wait till tomorrow for me, it's late here and I'm typing this on my phone. Is this WP 3.0 or 3.1 already?

Comment: @Jan Great! That is great news. Yes, I'm running the latest 3.0.5. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the rewrite analyzer, `/projects/page/2/` sets `projects=page&page=/2` instead of `pagename=projects&paged=2` as we would like. So you just need to add a rewrite rule for this special case (in the `register_projects()` function, after you register your custom post type, would be a good place):

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'projects/page/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=projects&paged=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

Remember to flush your rewrite rules, by visiting the *Permalinks* page or by some other way.

Comment: thank you so much. It worked! This may be a dumb question but will this continue to work for pages 3, 4, 5, etc? Also, if I register a different post type in the future, do I have to add a similar rewrite rule?

Comment: @John: The `[0-9]+` matches *anything from 0-9* (`[0-9]`) *multiple times* (`+`), so yes, it will work for higher numbers. If you add new post types you will have to do this again for each taxonomy. However, if you wait a bit longer and can use WordPress 3.1, you should register your custom post type with the new `has_archive` argument, which will create the archives without you having to create a "fake" page with a template.

Comment: Thank you I will keep that in mind. I hope there will be a tutorial on how to register custom post types with the `has_archive` argument. You're a life-saver!

Comment: ok, thanks - but i dont read this in the question, i had understand, he search a way for an pagination with the plugin for custom post types and i think, the better way as this plugin is a core function. But it is right, the pagination with permalinks is with this function not ready.

Comment: with the release of 3.1, I couldn't help but think back to this question and the use of the new `has_archive` argument. I tried adding `'has_archive' => true` to the array of arguments; however, my projects page showed the archive page when I went to site.com/projects. Additionally, I tried `'has_archive' => projects` and that did the same thing. I'm wondering how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Its a better way, you build your own paginatin:

```
echo paginate_links(array(
  'current' => 5,
  'total' => 9,
  'prev_text' => '&laquo; Prev'
));
```

or via custom solutions, see this 2 posts:

- http://wpengineer.com/2078/custom-pagination-without-wordpress-plugins/
- http://wpengineer.com/2133/wordpress-pagination-again/

Comment: I keep wanting to recommend that function myself, only problem is it's not the easiest function to make sense of(you get my vote though, i'd love to see users utilising this function alot more, instead of choosing to use pagenavi). Small note to others reading, it's the very same function you'll see used extensively throughout the WordPress administration area.

Comment: But I don't think the problem here is creating the navigation links, but handling the incoming URL. Both functions will probably generate the link `/projects/page/2/`, but I doubt any of them changes the rewrite rules to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I am all for creating my own pagination but as @Jan mentioned, won't both functions generate the same link?I'm wondering how others have handled this problem. Some have reported to have changed the name of the post type to its singular form (e.g. project) while keeping its plural form (e.g. projects) for the name of the page. However, if I change the name of the post type to singular, that gets reflected in the url as I mentioned (e.g. mysite.com/project/single-post) which then messes up the pagination since the url should be mysite.com/projects/single-post.

Comment: By the way, thank you. I've followed your advice in using paginate_links and have gotten rid of pagenavi :)